# Zend Framework urls

Tags: zend-framework, url

I have a zend framework application and it seems to be running correctly, i can access my app at domain.com/controller/action for the IndexController. I have now made a new controller and i am getting "page cannot be displayed".

I can however access my new controller at this address  domain.com/index.php/controller/action

I have checked all the usual things AllowOverride is on, rewrite is enabled, the htaccess file is the default one created when you make a Zend sample project. I feel like I have missed something fundamental, if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up routes to control how ZF routes (translates) your requested URL into specific controller / actions.

Take a look into the Zend Framework routing docs [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html)

Try adding something like this to your application.ini:

> resources.router.routes.routename.route = "/myroute/"
>   resources.router.routes.routename.defaults.controller = mycontroller
>   resources.router.routes.routename.defaults.action = myaction

**EDIT**: you may have a problem with your rewrite after re-reading your question :) you mention that allowoverride is on - what's the exact line in your config?

Try "AllowOverride FileInfo" or "AllowOverride All" if your requests aren't getting routed through your index.php at all as it seems might be the case.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you, am reading that now. Am I incorrect in thinking that one of the features of the framework is to automatically direct app users to the correct, controller and action based on the url, and well structured files?

Comment: My line is and was always as follows: "AllowOverride all"

Comment: That's right, your URL doesn't have to have a 1:1 mapping with a particular controller or action

Check out the routing docs and see if that helps - your configuration looks okay from what I can tell

Comment: (As I had a feeling that my app config and zend structure was fine) I uploaded my test app to my live server (mine is running locally using WAMP Server) and it worked...the files are the same (.htaccess and all) and my apache virtual host configs are the same. Now i am a little lost as to what else could be causing the problem?

Comment: Only thing I can think of is reloading apache to ensure mod_rewrite is active

Also if you are using aliases rather than virtual hosts that can apparently conflict with mod_rewrite in windows

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be `symlinks`

here is an example vhost that works

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\www\zf2-tutorial\public"
    ServerName zf2-tutorial.local
    ErrorLog "C:\Zend\ZendServer\logs\zf2-tutorial.local.log"
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <directory "C:\www\zf2-tutorial">
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    </directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I think your problem might be the `Options Indexes FollowSymlinks` is not present.

Your urls should work with `domain.com/module/controller/action` although it may display as `domain.com/index.php/module/controller/action`. There are a few ways to remove the `index.php`from the displayed url. The method I use is to add this line to the top of my `index.php`

`$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = str_replace('index.php','',$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);`